# Is a scalar extension of an $(t)$-adically complete module complete?

Tags: homological-algebra, extension-field, topological-vector-spaces, limits-colimits

Let $M$ be a $(t)$-adically complete $\mathbb C[[t]]$-module, say $M$ is a topologically free $\mathbb C[[t]]$-module. Let $\mathbb C((t))$ be the field of formal Laurent series. Is then the scalar extension
$$M\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]}\mathbb C((t))$$
$(t)$-adically complete? It is hard for me to verify this since I cannot figure out if the inverse limit commutes in this case with the tensor product. Does it make sense at all to talk about $(t)$-adic completeness in the case of a $\mathbb C((t))$-vector space?

Comment: What is $h$ in $h$-adic? Do you mean the natural topology coming from the maximal ideal of the power series ring?

Comment: Indeed, I mean actually the $(t)$-adic topology, where $(t)$ is the maximal ideal in $\mathbb C[[t]]$. I made a typo which I will correct now. Thank you for the observation!

Comment: What is a topologically free module? Are you saying that $M$ is basically $\mathbb C[[t]]^n$? If not, can you define it?

Comment: A module $M$ over $\mathbb C[[t]]$ is called topologically free if it is isomorphic to $V[[t]]$ for some complex vector space $V$, which does not have to be finite dimensional. Pay attention that $V[[t]]\cong V\hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[[t]]$.

Comment: But the question is not just about topologically free modules. It is for every $(t)$-adically complete module $M$. In the literature, some authors complete the tensor product $M\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]}\mathbb C((t))$ without explaining with respect to what while other authors seem not to complete it. I am trying to find out the underlying reason for that.